# How to sort new questions by votes

Tags: support, search, sorting

Suppose I want to sort questions by votes asked in the last 3 days. Can this be done? It is already great that users can view questions based on "newest" and "votes" options, but I am wondering whether one can combine these two criteria.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching)
for questions from a certain time period and then order the
search results by number of votes, for example
[created:2013-08-26..2013-08-29 is:question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2013-08-26..2013-08-29%20is%3aquestion) or
[lastactive:2013-08-26..2013-08-29 is:question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lastactive%3a2013-08-26..2013-08-29%20is%3aquestion).

Comment: Great answer, Martin. Thanks!